# R function to create data.frame based on variable in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and having some trouble. If I have a df call 'xyz' as below.

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | Three |
| x | 2 | Three |
| y | 1 | Three |
| y | 0 | Three |
| z | 2 | Three |
| z | 1 | Three |

from the df above, I want to crate separate data frames named with variables in c1 such as:

data frame name 'x'

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | Three |
| x | 2 | Three |

data frame name 'y'

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| y | 1 | Three |
| y | 0 | Three |

data frame name 'z'

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| z | 2 | Three |
| z | 1 | Three |

sorry if it is already answered but I couldn't find any good solution for now.

Comment: Try `split(df,df$C1)`

Comment: Thank you so much it is working but how do we save those separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to R its ideal to stick to base R.
But keeping a dplyr option for future use as well.

```
df %>%
  group_by(`C1`) %>%
  group_walk( ~ write_csv(
    .x,
    paste0(
      "path_to_your_folder",
      "file_prefix_if_required_",
      .y$C1,
      ".csv"
    ) #paste0 function willbuild a custom filename as per your needs
  ), .keep = TRUE) #.keep=T will keep the grouped column in the file.
```

Pls check help on *dplyr::group_walk* and it has an example as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try `list2env(split(df,df$C1),envir=.GlobalEnv)`.
This will split df by C1 and save each dataframe into a variable with the name of the C1 value.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I want to do. Thank you!