# I have a data frame for hotel bookings over 3 years I want to sperate each year into its own dateframe and also each month

Tags: r

I have a dataframe https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ebOpYgAxA8EqECkZZT4F5blHF7gYCDKAPgLM5ZWHpk/edit?usp=sharing

I want to make each year its own DF and each month for each year using R what code would I use to do this?

Im new to R I know how you would do this in sheets but R is throwing me for a bit of a loop I know I could use filter() but thought heir might a easier way other than having to make 3 DFs as sheets then using filter() in R to make to DFs by month.

Comment: `split(dat, dat[c("year","month")])` (names notwithstanding, I haven't downloaded your data). Having said that, it is commonly better to keep the data together so that processes you do to one year/month are done simultaneously to all years/months. This typically requires a grouping operation, e.g., `dplyr::group_by` or base's `aggregate`, `split`/`\`split<-\``, etc. Can you explain why you think splitting it into multiple frames it necessary?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since its a personal project I want to split it up because in there real world that's what the end user would be looking at. For example, hotel data managers at various hotels are looking at past traffic patterns and most likely wouldn't have access to or the ability to use a program. splitting them and then plotting them with visuals seems the most sensible way to show that data to the end user,

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can find out `distinct` year and month in your data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
hotel %>% distinct(arrival_date_year, arrival_date_month) # I saved your data as hotel.
```

Then, make data frames for each combination of year and month.

```
July2015 <- hotel %>% filter(arrival_date_year==2015, arrival_date_month=='July') %>% View()
August2015 <- hotel %>% filter(arrival_date_year==2015, arrival_date_month=='August') %>% View()
```

You can also try

```
list2env(split(hotel,hotel$arrival_date_year, hotel$arrival_date_month),envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

This will make a separate data frame for each year, as suggested by @user2974951 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70737947/12354196